# What happened to the Unofficial John Steakley website www.johnsteakley.com?

Tags: john-steakley

Does anyone know what happened to the http://www.johnsteakley.com website?

It seems a Japanese company now holds the domain name?

[image: Current state of www.johnsteakley.com]

Comment: Fleet obviously isn't there.

Answer (score 12):

Wow, just kind of stumbled on this while goofing off at work.  Sorry, I wish I'd found it when it was new!  I was the webmaster for `www.johnsteakley.com`.  I ran it for around 14 years, first as a hobby right out of college on the old aol boards then later at the `johnsteakley.com` domain.

What happened?  Well, I had 3 kids and a career and got older and web development got more and more complicated and my skills couldn't keep up.  Then Steakley passed away and activity in the bulletin board slowed down more and more.  It got to a point where the site was very outdated (it was the third version of the site), I didn't have the skill set to do an update, no one had posted in over a month, and I couldn't justify paying another chunk of money to renew the registration on the domain.

I offered it to all the other fans on the bulletin board but no one took me up on it, and, well... after 14 years we let it go.  Sad, but it was time for me to move on.

Comment: Excellent answer from a truly authoritative source! I have taken the liberty to suggest some minor formatting to make the answer slightly more readable; hope you agree with it, otherwise feel free to revert.

Comment: Egosurfing your email address were we?

Comment: Hello Dave, welcome to [fantasy.se]. Thank you for your answer. If you're interested in SF & Fantasy, perhaps you'd like to stick around. We have some other questions about John Steakley here, tagged [tag:john-steakley] or [tag:armor-book]. May I invite you to take the [tour]?

Answer (score 6):

On September 9th the domain lapsed through non-payment. The site registrar (NETWORK SOLUTIONS) appear to have passed control over to a company called ビジネスフォン 周辺機器のご案内.

You can view a snapshot of the old website [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140517115440/http://johnsteakley.com/). After his death in 2010, the site's owner (Davidalpern@aol.com) added a link to Steakley's obituary. That appears to have been the site's final update.

Comment: "After his death in 2010, the site's owner (Davidalpern@aol.com) added a link to Steakley's obituary." - not knowing that the person the website was *about* had passed away, I had to read that sentence several times to figure out who did what ;)